# react-bootstrap-table - column with own data (not from dataset)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

Hello I have a table with some columns, data is taken from an API. Now I need to add another column where I will add a button with my own functionality (different functionality for each row). Can I somehow do it?

```
    <BootstrapTable
      data={content}
      version="4"
      striped
      hover
      remote
      fetchInfo={{ dataTotalSize: totalSize }}
      pagination
      options={{
        onPageChange: this.onPageChange,
        hideSizePerPage: true,
        page: filters.page + 1,
        sizePerPage: filters.size,
        onFilterChange: this.onFilterChange,
      }}
      keyField="id"
      trClassName="tableRow"
      containerClass={content.length > 0 ? 'fullTable' : undefined}
    >
      {tableHeaders.map(header => (
        <TableHeaderColumn
          filter={header.filter}
          key={header.id}
          dataField={header.id}
          thStyle={{
            whiteSpace: 'normal',
            textAlign: 'center',
            lineHeight: 2,
          }}
          dataFormat={header.date && this.dateFormatter}
          width={header.width}
        >
            {header.name}
        </TableHeaderColumn>
      ))}
    </BootstrapTable>
```

I am using `"react-bootstrap-table": "4.3.1"`.

Comment: You are using the [old bootstrap table](https://github.com/AllenFang/react-bootstrap-table) new one does not use `TableHeaderColumn`. Documentation of the new table can be found [here](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/storybook/index.html?selectedKind=Welcome&selectedStory=react%20bootstrap%20table%202%20&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel).

Comment: Maybe [custom row selection](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/storybook/index.html?selectedKind=Row%20Selection&selectedStory=Custom%20Selection&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel) can work for you. Or [dummy column](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/storybook/index.html?selectedKind=Work%20on%20Columns&selectedStory=Dummy%20Column&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel)

Comment: HMR yes i know, in my project I must use the old ver.

Comment: unfortunately custom row selection can't do it...

Comment: Did you try `tableHeaders` to have one more item that has a formatter returning a react component? You could pass the current data item as props to this component and give it an onClick.

Comment: well its sounds like it could work, BUT there is nothing in API so i cannot pass any onClick or sth like this....

Comment: You can try: `[{dataFormat:()=>(<button onClick={()=>console.log(header)}>hello world</button>)}]`